# what is another word you would call or label someone that you feel isnt on your level?

Tags: single-word-requests

the word is on the tip on my tounge, its a word you would use to compare two people or things.

a word you word use to tell someone that they are below you, not as smart , or strong...

Comment: Can you give a sentence with a blank where you expect your word to go? And make it so the context would allow you to infer the meaning of the word?

Comment: im trying to think of one its also like saying someone isnt as capable as you are:

Comment: my husband doesnt trust me \have faith in me that i can fix the printer he doesnt think im as _____ as he is...

Comment: he doesn't think you are as *competent* as he is, but it doesn't really fit the question!

Answer (score 1):

The word pair is **inferiors** and **superiors**.

> **inferior**:
>   2. lower in place or position; closer to the bottom or base:
>   3. of comparatively low grade; poor in quality; substandard:
>   an inferior product.
>   4. less important, valuable, or worthy:
>   5.  acting or performing in a way that is comparatively poor or mediocre:
>   - [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/inferior)